# Self join in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'am intermediate in mongoDB. I'am having document like following.

Collection:- nodeDetails

```
{
_id:ObjectId("3df61406-a65c-480d-b258-85786caa871e"),
"model":["nnn","mmm"]
childrens: ["2a865da0-fbe1-4842-954d-8c7b527f8bd1", "8d06e6af-5f68-4559-9712-706afed5c0db"]
},
{
_id:ObjectId("2a865da0-fbe1-4842-954d-8c7b527f8bd1"),
"model":["nnn","mmm"],
childrens: ["4f84d69a-94da-4219-a85d-0293a615da8d", "5e55c16f-1b39-48ca-8f79-7acc373dca13"]
},
{
_id:ObjectId("4f84d69a-94da-4219-a85d-0293a615da8d"),
"model":["nnn","mmm"],
childrens: []
},
{
_id:ObjectId("5e55c16f-1b39-48ca-8f79-7acc373dca13"),
"model":["nnn","mmm"],
childrens: ["fb47003b-8b9f-4c1c-bc6c-cf51c0dbb8bc"]
},
{
_id:ObjectId("8d06e6af-5f68-4559-9712-706afed5c0db"),
"model":["nnn","mmm"],
childrens:[]
},
{
_id:ObjectId("fb47003b-8b9f-4c1c-bc6c-cf51c0dbb8bc"),
"model":["nnn","mmm"],
childrens:[]
}
```

I need to fetch data from root (ObjectId("3df61406-a65c-480d-b258-85786caa871e")) to last child. I need a query to get the following output.

```
{
 _id:ObjectId("3df61406-a65c-480d-b258-85786caa871e"),
 "model":["nnn","mmm"]
 childrens: [
 {
     _id:ObjectId("2a865da0-fbe1-4842-954d-8c7b527f8bd1"),
     "model":["nnn","mmm"],
      childrens: [
      {
          _id:ObjectId("4f84d69a-94da-4219-a85d-0293a615da8d"),
          "model":["nnn","mmm"],
          childrens: []
      },
      {
          _id:ObjectId("5e55c16f-1b39-48ca-8f79-7acc373dca13"),
          "model":["nnn","mmm"],
          childrens: [
          {
              _id:ObjectId("fb47003b-8b9f-4c1c-bc6c-cf51c0dbb8bc"),
              "model":["nnn","mmm"],
              childrens:[]
          }
          ]
      }
      ]
 },
 {
     _id:ObjectId("8d06e6af-5f68-4559-9712-706afed5c0db"),
     "model":["nnn","mmm"],
     childrens:[]
 }]
 }
```

I have tried the following query, but that was also not giving exact output.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "3df61406-a65c-480d-b258-85786caa871e"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$childrens"
  },
  {
    $graphLookup: {
      from: "collection",
      startWith: "$childrens",
      connectFromField: "childrens",
      connectToField: "_id",
      as: "childrensList"
    }
  }
])
```

How to do self join in mongodb? is it possible ? I'am using mongdb 4.4.4 version. any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try $graphlookup- Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/mXGeWbB79CD

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar that query not giving exact output as i posted.